# WebRTC renegotiate the Peer Connection to switch streams

Tags: javascript, node.js, video, webrtc

I have this script where. two users can chat using webrtc. when two users enter to the chat room . the text chat is started automatically. 
I want to add a botton to allow video chat. for example there is two users. user_1 and user_2 when they enter to the chat room, the text chat is initiated, they can send text messages to each others, and when user_1 click on the video icon the user_2 can see user_1. and the same thing with the user_2 when he click on video icon.
This is the code i'm using now. but this code doesn't work properly, when i stat chatting with someone and i click on video icon i can see my self but the other user can't see me.I didn't post all the code because it's more than 300 lines, but i think you cant help me to modify just this to make it work, and thanks in advance everyone.

```
var pc_config = webrtcDetectedBrowser === 'firefox' ?
{'iceServers':[{'url':'stun:23.21.150.121'}]} : // IP address
{'iceServers': [{'url': 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'}]};
var pc_constraints = {
  'optional': [
    {'DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement': true},
    {'RtpDataChannels': true}
  ]};
var sdpConstraints = {'mandatory': {
  'OfferToReceiveAudio':true,
  'OfferToReceiveVideo':true }};
var constraints = {video: true, audio: true};
var v_on_off = false;
v_call.on('click', function(){
  if (!v_on_off) {
        navigator.getUserMedia(constraints, handleUserMedia, handleUserMediaError);
        if (isInitiator) {
            maybeStart();
        };
      v_on_off = true;
  } else {
      // stop stream
  }
});
function handleUserMedia(stream) {
        localStream = stream;
        attachMediaStream(localVideo, stream);
        sendMessage('got user media');
}
var socket = io.connect();
if (room !== '') {
  socket.emit('create or join', room);
}
socket.on('created', function (room){
  isInitiator = true;
});
socket.on('join', function (room){
  isChannelReady = true;
});
socket.on('joined', function (room){
  isChannelReady = true;
});
function sendMessage(message){
  socket.emit('message', message);
}
// this will start a text chat between too peers
sendMessage('got user media');
if (isInitiator) {
    maybeStart();
  }
socket.on('message', function (message){
  console.log('Received message:', message);
  if (message === 'got user media') {
    maybeStart();
  } else if (message.type === 'offer') {
    if (!isInitiator && !isStarted) {
      maybeStart();
    }
    pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(message));
    doAnswer();
  } else if (message.type === 'answer' && isStarted) {
    pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(message));
  } else if (message.type === 'candidate' && isStarted) {
    var candidate = new RTCIceCandidate({sdpMLineIndex:message.label,
      candidate:message.candidate});
    pc.addIceCandidate(candidate);
  } else if (message === 'bye' && isStarted) {
    handleRemoteHangup();
  }
});
function maybeStart() {
  if (!isStarted && isChannelReady) {
    createPeerConnection();
    isStarted = true;
    if (isInitiator) {
      doCall();
    }
  }
}
function createPeerConnection() {
  try {
    pc = new RTCPeerConnection(pc_config, pc_constraints);
    if (typeof localStream != 'undefined') {
        pc.addStream(localStream);
    }
    pc.onicecandidate = handleIceCandidate;
  } catch (e) {
    alert('Cannot create RTCPeerConnection object.');
      return;
  }
  pc.onaddstream = handleRemoteStreamAdded;
  pc.onremovestream = handleRemoteStreamRemoved;
  if (isInitiator) {
    try {
      // Reliable Data Channels not yet supported in Chrome
      sendChannel = pc.createDataChannel("sendDataChannel",
        {reliable: false});
      sendChannel.onmessage = handleMessage;
      trace('Created send data channel');
    } catch (e) {
      alert('Failed to create data channel. ' +
            'You need Chrome M25 or later with RtpDataChannel enabled');
      trace('createDataChannel() failed with exception: ' + e.message);
    }
    sendChannel.onopen = handleSendChannelStateChange;
    sendChannel.onclose = handleSendChannelStateChange;
  } else {
    pc.ondatachannel = gotReceiveChannel;
  }
}
function gotReceiveChannel(event) {
  trace('Receive Channel Callback');
  sendChannel = event.channel;
  sendChannel.onmessage = handleMessage;
  sendChannel.onopen = handleReceiveChannelStateChange;
  sendChannel.onclose = handleReceiveChannelStateChange;
}
function handleSendChannelStateChange() {
  var readyState = sendChannel.readyState;
  trace('Send channel state is: ' + readyState);
  enableMessageInterface(readyState == "open");
}
function handleReceiveChannelStateChange() {
  var readyState = sendChannel.readyState;
  trace('Receive channel state is: ' + readyState);
  enableMessageInterface(readyState == "open");
}
function handleIceCandidate(event) {
  console.log('handleIceCandidate event: ', event);
  if (event.candidate) {
    sendMessage({
      type: 'candidate',
      label: event.candidate.sdpMLineIndex,
      id: event.candidate.sdpMid,
      candidate: event.candidate.candidate});
  } else {
    console.log('End of candidates.');
  }
}
function doCall() {
  var constraints = {'optional': [], 'mandatory': {'MozDontOfferDataChannel': true}};
  // temporary measure to remove Moz* constraints in Chrome
  if (webrtcDetectedBrowser === 'chrome') {
    for (var prop in constraints.mandatory) {
      if (prop.indexOf('Moz') !== -1) {
        delete constraints.mandatory[prop];
      }
     }
   }
  constraints = mergeConstraints(constraints, sdpConstraints);
  console.log('Sending offer to peer, with constraints: \n' +
    '  \'' + JSON.stringify(constraints) + '\'.');
  pc.createOffer(setLocalAndSendMessage, null, constraints);
}
function doAnswer() {
  console.log('Sending answer to peer.');
  pc.createAnswer(setLocalAndSendMessage, null, sdpConstraints);
}
function handleRemoteStreamAdded(event) {
  console.log('Remote stream added.');
  attachMediaStream(remoteVideo, event.stream);
  remoteStream = event.stream;
}
```

and this is a server side code :

```
socket.on('message', function (message) {
    // channel-only broadcast...
    socket.broadcast.to(message.channel).emit('message', message);
});
// Handle 'create or join' messages
socket.on('create or join', function (room) {
    var numClients = io.sockets.clients(room).length;
    // First client joining...
    if (numClients == 0){
        socket.join(room);
        socket.emit('created', room);
    } else if (numClients == 1) {
        io.sockets.in(room).emit('join', room);
        socket.join(room);
        socket.emit('joined', room);
    } else { 
    socket.emit('full', room);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 8):

### Renegotiate

In short, in order to add video or audio to an existing connection, you need to *renegotiate* the connection every time you make a media change. Basically you register a listener:

```
pc.onnegotiationneeded = function() {
  pc.createOffer(setLocalAndSendMessage, null);
};
```

that fires off another round-trip of offer/answer exchange, just like the one that initiated the connection.

Once you have that, a `negotiationneeded` event will fire from actions that need renegotiation. For example, an "Add Video" button:

```
AddVideoButton.onclick = function() {
  navigator.getUserMedia(constraints, handleUserMedia, handleUserMediaError);
};
```

Once both sides have updated, you should be in business.

See [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29511602/how-to-exchange-streams-from-two-peerconnections-with-offer-answer/29530757#29530757) for a full example (Firefox-only due to arrow-functions, sorry).

### Spec nits:

It looks like you're using [adapter.js](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter) the cross-browser webrtc polyfill to take care of differences between browsers, which is great! But other parts of your example are Chrome-specific or outdated, and unless you follow [the standard](http://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc) wont work on other browsers. You didn't tag your question as Chrome-specific, so if you don't mind:

The browser-detection in your `pc_config` is no longer needed as of Firefox 32 (over a year ago). Instead I would use (note `urls` plural):

```
var config = { iceServers: [{urls: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'}] };
```

The `pc_constraints` (early Chrome) and `sdpConstraints` are non-standard. `createOffer` now takes [RTCOfferOptions](http://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#idl-def-RTCOfferOptions), a simple dictionary, rather than constraints (also note lower-case 'o's):

```
var options = { offerToReceiveAudio: true, offerToReceiveVideo: true };
```

If you're using a recent version of [adapter.js](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter) then this should just work.

Lastly, data-channels over RTP is non-standard (and no longer needed I think?)

Comment: can you tell me what to modify in my code , i'm just a beginner i didn't write this code i just copier it from a website and i did some changes on it . so i want to add that functionality ( button video ) . can you please help me

Comment: I've adjusted my answer a bit. Hope it helps steer you in the right direction. Try adding video from the side that initiated the call first, as that's most likely to work without issue.

Comment: it didn't work . i did spend 3 months trying to make it work i did read 3 books about webrtc i learned nodejs just to make this chat website . i guess it's time to give up.anyway thanks for your help

Comment: Did you try the working Firefox example I linked to? It does what you're asking. You should be able to adapt that to your needs. Look in web console for any errors.

Answer (score -1):

You should just set DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement in pc_constraint to true, and it`s will work fine

```
 var pc_constraints = {
    optional: [{ 'DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement': true }]
  };
```