# WebRTC: Renegotiation in firefox

Tags: firefox, webrtc

According to [this article](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/03/webrtc-in-firefox-38-multistream-and-renegotiation/), re-negotiation is implemented in firefox v38 and we can add remove streams from same peerconnections without creating new ones, but I am unable to find any working demos to support that claim, and when I tried it, two users chating in video mode, I changing one of their stream to `audio`, I get the error:

> NotSupportedError: removeStream not yet implemented

[this](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=844295) tells the same, but [this](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=857115) tells renegotiation events are supported, but isn't `removeStream` key part of renegotiation? I am using firefox version 39 in windows 7. I am confused, renegotiation is not yet supported in firefox, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `replaceTrack` for individual tracks, instead of replacing the entire stream. This example assumes you have a peer connection `pc1` and a new stream `newStream` to replace on it. Get the senders, and replace the tracks with appropriate tracks from the new stream. Working sample [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8nem95k7/).

```
Promise.all(pc1.getSenders().map(sender =>
  sender.replaceTrack((sender.track.kind == "audio")?
                      newStream.getAudioTracks()[0] :
                      newStream.getVideoTracks()[0])))
.then(() => log("Flip!"))
.catch(failed);
```

Also note this, from your first link:

```
function screenShare() {
    let screenConstraints = {video: {mediaSource: "screen"}};

    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(screenConstraints)
    .then(stream) {
        stream.getTracks().forEach(track) {
            screenStream = stream;
            screenSenders.push(pc1.addTrack(track, stream));
        });
    });
}
```

Notice that this example calls `pc1.addTrack` not `pc1.addStream`

And in the same in reverse, for removing - `pc1.removeTrack`:

```
function stopScreenShare() {
    screenStream.stop();
    screenSenders.forEach(sender) {
        pc1.removeTrack(sender);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Renegotiation *is* supported in Firefox.

Firefox just never implemented `removeStream` because [the spec](http://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#rtcpeerconnection-interface-extensions) had changed to `addTrack` and `removeTrack` by the time renegotiation was implemented (some are suggesting that its removal was too hasty, so it may come back). `addStream` still works for backwards compatibility, because Firefox already supported it.

Note that `removeTrack` confusingly takes the [RTCRtpSender](http://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#idl-def-RTCRtpSender) returned from `addTrack` so the API is not a drop-in.

A polyfill would look something like this:

```
mozRTCPeerConnection.prototype.removeStream = function(stream) {
  this.getSenders().forEach(sender =>
      stream.getTracks().includes(sender.track) && this.removeTrack(sender));
}
```

The move to tracks was done to give users more flexibility, since tracks may belong to multiple streams, and not all tracks in a stream need be sent over a PeerConnection (or the same PeerConnection).

See this [answer to a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29511602/how-to-exchange-streams-from-two-peerconnections-with-offer-answer/29530757#29530757) for a renegotiation example that works in Firefox.