# WebRTC pause and resume stream

Tags: javascript, html, video-streaming, webrtc

I am trying to use WebRTC to build a web application that needs to pause/resume the video/audio stream when some events trigger. I have tried the `getTracks()[0].stop()` but I am not sure how to resume the stream. Are there any advice on that? thanks

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`getTracks()[0].stop()` is permanent.

Use `getTracks()[0].enabled = false` instead. To unpause `getTracks()[0].enabled = true`.

This will replace your video with black, and your audio with silence.

Try it (use [https fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p0jqedba/) for Chrome):

```js
var pc1 = new RTCPeerConnection(), pc2 = new RTCPeerConnection();

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true })
  .then(stream => pc1.addStream(video1.srcObject = stream))
  .catch(log);

var mute = () => video1.srcObject.getTracks().forEach(t => t.enabled = !t.enabled);

var add = (pc, can) => can && pc.addIceCandidate(can).catch(log);
pc1.onicecandidate = e => add(pc2, e.candidate);
pc2.onicecandidate = e => add(pc1, e.candidate);

pc2.onaddstream = e => video2.srcObject = e.stream;
pc1.onnegotiationneeded = e =>
  pc1.createOffer().then(d => pc1.setLocalDescription(d))
  .then(() => pc2.setRemoteDescription(pc1.localDescription))
  .then(() => pc2.createAnswer()).then(d => pc2.setLocalDescription(d))
  .then(() => pc1.setRemoteDescription(pc2.localDescription))
  .catch(log);

var log = msg => div.innerHTML += "<br>" + msg;
```

```html
<video id="video1" height="120" width="160" autoplay muted></video>
<video id="video2" height="120" width="160" autoplay></video><br>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="mute()">mute</input><div id="div"></div>
<script src="https://webrtc.github.io/adapter/adapter-latest.js"></script>
```

PeerConnections basically stop sending packets in this muted state, so it is highly efficient.

Comment: The last sentence is unclear. Will "black video" and "silence" still use similar resources as before disabled (decoding/rendering, data transmission, etc)?

Comment: @JSON I've updated the answer to clarify that it hardly uses any resources. I confirmed it using stats in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ec9ossmu/) (requires Firefox for spec-stats atm). Thanks for catching that it was unclear.

Comment: Can you explain what happens to bandwidth?

Comment: I think i still receive track, but how can pause a particular transreceiver.sender(Audio/Video) from remote side with negotiation and without it ?

Comment: I changed direction attr from receiver side to 'inactive' and On the receiver side, the bandwidth decreased, do you think it's true way for pause audio/video ?

Comment: @J4v4d Right, to pause from the remote end is a different question, and changing `direction` is one way to go there. See [my blog post](https://blog.mozilla.org/webrtc/rtcrtptransceiver-explored/) for the myriad ways to control a track remotely.

Comment: is there any way out for just pausing the steaming simply instead of receiving blank frames , because I am sending those frames to the backend for processing

Answer (score 2):

You should try using renegotiation, I believe the difference still exists how it is done in chrome and firefox:

- In chrome, you just call `addStream` or `removeStream` on the `PeerConnection` object to add/ remove the stream, then create and exchange `sdp`.
- In firefox, there is no direct `removeStream`, you need to use [RTCRtpSender](http://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#idl-def-RTCRtpSender) and `addTrack` and `removeTrack` methods, you can take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31338235/webrtc-renegotiation-in-firefox)

Comment: in my case, idk how `addTrack` didnt work, but **`rtcRtpSender.replaceTrack(track);`** worked. \
see: [java - can we remove and add audio stream dynamically in webRTC video call without renegotiation - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56944864/can-we-remove-and-add-audio-stream-dynamically-in-webrtc-video-call-without-rene)

Answer (score 0):

Below code can work perfect under Mac and Windows Chrome after version 117.

At each condition including tab(with or without audio), window or full screen(with or without audio).

Freeze at the last screen and resume fast.

```
const pc = new RTCPeerConnection(servers);

...

const pause=()=>{
    pc.getSenders().forEach(sender=>{
        console.log(sender.track.kind+' pause');//audio(if it exists) and video
        const parameters=sender.getParameters();
        parameters.encodings[0].active=false;
        sender.setParameters(parameters);
    });
};

const resume=()=>{
    pc.getSenders().forEach(sender=>{
        console.log(sender.track.kind+' resume');
        const parameters=sender.getParameters();
        parameters.encodings[0].active=true;
        sender.setParameters(parameters);
    });
};
```