# What steps are needed to change a WebRTC audio stream to a video stream?

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, webrtc, audio-streaming

I am developing Audio call and video call. Just imagine 2 users are doing audio call. Is there any possible to change the audio call to a video call? What steps are needed to change audio stream to video stream?

Comment: you can take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35857576/webrtc-pause-and-resume-stream/35857966) and [jib's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35872215/3074768) to it, you can do something similar.

Comment: I think this should be re-opened, as the duplicate question is browser and platform specific. There's a good general answer to this, based on the WebRTC specification, which works on browsers more caught up with the spec in this particular area.