# WebRTC: removeStream and then re- addStream after negotiation: Safe?

Tags: webrtc

After a WebRTC session has been established, I would like to stop sending the stream to the peer at some point and then resume sending later.

If I call removeStream, it does indeed stop sending data. If I then call addStream (with the previously removed stream), it resumes. Great!

However, is this safe? Or do I need to re-negotiate/exchange the SDP after the removal and/or after the re-add? I've seen it mentioned in several places that the SDP needs to be re-negotiated after such changes, but I'm wondering if it is ok in this simple case where the same stream is being removed and re-added?

PS: Just in case anyone wants to suggest it: I don't want to change the enabled state of the track since I still need the local stream playing, even while it is not being sent to the peer.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "safe"? Not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Based on your answer, you knew what I was asking. :) Safe, as in, is it legitimate or is it a fluke that it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will only work in Chrome, and is non-spec, so it's neither web compatible nor future-proof.

The [spec](http://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#rtcpeerconnection-interface-extensions) has pivoted from streams to tracks, sporting `addTrack` and `removeTrack` instead of `addStream` and `removeStream`. As a result the latter [isn't even implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31356795/918910) in Firefox.

Unfortunately, because Chrome hasn't caught up, this means renegotiation currently works differently in different browsers. [It is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35515536/918910) to do however with some effort.

The new model has a cleaner separation between streams and what's sent in RTCPeerConnection.

Instead of renegotiating, setting `track.enabled = false` is a good idea. You can still play a local view of your video by [cloning](https://jsfiddle.net/zvLd6hc0/) the track.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer! This says it all.