# removeStream is not working in firefox and removetrack is not working in chrome even after adapter.js

Tags: webrtc

I'm using adapter.js, but I still get an error when using `removeStream` and `removeTrack`.

```
Error in firefox: NotSupportedError: removeStream not yet implemented
```

Comment: [`removeStream`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31356795/918910) was never implemented in Firefox because the spec dropped it before it could be implemented there. [`removeTrack`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/removeTrack) takes a sender as an argument, and unfortunately is hard for adapter to polyfill since it relies on the browser exposing track-level attachments, which Chrome does not yet.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have implemented pollyfills for this